# What type of object is required for IViewRefresh.RefreshItem "Data" parameter?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

Esri's [help for this method](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IViewRefresh_RefreshItem.htm) specifies this as LPUNKNOWN, which is rather unhelpful since I don't speak COM.  I've tried an envelope, a geometry, and a graphicsContainer; each time receiving "System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.".  Can't find any meaningful examples.  Here's my MCVE . . .

```
IMap newDataFrame = new Map
{
    Name = "New Data Frame",
    SpatialReference = CurrentMap.SpatialReference
};
var viewRefresh = (IViewRefresh) newDataFrame;
var graphicsContainer = (IGraphicsContainer) newDataFrame;
var pointMaker = IdioticThingWithWhichYouNeedNotConcernYourself();
CurrentMxDocument.Maps.Add(newDataFrame);
CurrentMxDocument.UpdateContents();
...
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) 
{
    IMarkerElement element = pointMaker.MakePoint(out var envelope);
    graphicsContainer.AddElement((IElement)element, 0);
    viewRefresh.RefreshItem(graphicsContainer);
    // Also tried viewRefresh.RefreshItem(envelope);
}
```

I figure it's questionable (at best) to refresh even a tiny portion of a map 5000 times, but this is just tinkering so please humor me on that point. Regardless, the exception noted above is thrown the first time through the loop.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? If you're trying to draw a marker use IDisplay https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w000000pt000000 StartDrawing, SetSymbol, DrawPoint, FinishDrawing in that order or wire in IActiveViewEvents.ViewRefreshed event https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/ViewRefreshed_Event/0012000001mn000000/ and draw your point there (start/stop drawing not required).

Comment: Could the data parameter be a layer?

Comment: @Hornbydd that did it . . . sorta. Changing the last line to `viewRefresh.RefreshItem(newDataFrame.ActiveGraphicsLayer);` got me exceptionlessly through the loop. But the map doesn't refresh with every iteration as I expect, although that may be because the ActiveGraphicsLayer references something other than `newDataFrame as IGraphicsContainer`.  Anyway if you care to put that in an answer I'll accept it. Next I'll try the suggestion from @MichaelStimson because, yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: But wait . . . The graphics are removed from the map on the next refresh . . .

Comment: Yes, they're not *real* graphics, to make a *real* graphic use IMapFrame.Container https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000008q2000000 AddElement https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000005q8000000 to make an element that will be saved with the document - note these will be *permanent until deleted*.